# ValueError: Filename must be a string while uploading file to s3 bucket

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto3

I am sending an excel file as a request in postman and need to upload this to s3 .
I access the file from request and send it to s3.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def excel_upload(request):
    print("request", request)
    excel_file = request.FILES['file'] 
    print("excel_file", excel_file) // this prints the name of the excel file i am sending in request
    upload_to_aws(excel_file,'X1excelsheets','s3_file_name')
```

and here is the function to upload file to s3.

```
def upload_to_aws(local_file, bucket, s3_file):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                      aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

    try:
        s3.upload_file(local_file, bucket, s3_file)
        print("Upload Successful")
        return True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("The file was not found")
        return False
    except NoCredentialsError:
        print("Credentials not available")
        return False


uploaded = upload_to_aws('local_file', 'bucket_name', 's3_file_name')
```

I am trying to use this particular post

```
https://medium.com/bilesanmiahmad/how-to-upload-a-file-to-amazon-s3-in-python-68757a1867c6
```

to get things done .
Error:ValueError: Filename must be a string

Comment: Heyo - You are passing file as it is, `excel_file = request.FILES['file']`. Probably you should save it, and send to aws by "filename". So `excel_file='/path/to/file/file.xls'`

Comment: Why so ?I don't want to save it . I want it to be sent directly to aws s3 directly from the request .

Comment: Can u  suggest some method to achieve this ?

Comment: Sorry, not - what could be worth trying is: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=upload_file#S3.Bucket.upload_fileobj

Answer (score 5):

I made my configuration with [AWSCLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html)

```
S3_BUCKET_NAME = 'YOUR_BUCKET'

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    s3.upload_fileobj(f, S3_BUCKET_NAME, file)
```

I have been getting the same error so I just used **upload_fileobj** instead of **upload_file**. This worked fine for me, you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Save execel_file locally received from `request.POST.get('file_name')` in '/tmp' directory or according where your backend code will deploy, because upload_file takes path as string.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def excel_upload(request):
    excel_file = request.FILES['file']
    file_name = request.POST.get('file_name')
    with open('/tmp'+file_name, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in excel_file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
    upload_to_aws('/tmp' + file_name,'X1excelsheets','s3_file_name')
```

Update upload_to_aws as following.

```
client_s3.upload_file('/tmp/name.png', bucket, file_name, ExtraArgs={'ContentType': 'image/png'})
```